# how to defer compilation phase of the child directives unti the scope of parent directive has all data it requires

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html structure:

```
<my-parent-directive>
   <my-child-directive some-options="options">
```

And the controller for the `myParentDirective` which should instantiate `$scope`:

```
ng.module("some").directive("myParentDirective", ["someService", function(someService) {
    return {
        controller: function($scope) {
            someService.getData().then(function(options) {
                $scope.options = options;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Since `getData` method is asynchronous and may take a while to return the options which are essential for the child directive I need to suspend compilation\linking phase for the child directive until the `options` have arrived. How can I do that?

Comment: use `$timeout` may solve your problem..it will wait till directive DOM loaded

Comment: You shouldn't need to suspend compilation/linking. Could you provide more details why you would do that? I can't think of a good reason

Comment: @pixelbits, because the child directive needs `options` to be available before it starts to compile. I'm now thinking of using `ng-if` to wait until parent directive reports that it's initialized through scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually its quite possible by manually inserting your child code inside the parent directive after the data received. Here is an short example:

```
app.directive('myParentDirective', ["someService", function(someService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attr, controller, transclude) {
            someService.getData().then(function(options) {
                 $scope.options = options;

                 // Grab the inner content of the directive
                 var innerContent = transclude($scope, function() {});
                 // And place it inside & recompile it
                 element.html(innerContent);
                 // For angular version 1.2.17 or lesser, compile the content
                 $compile(element.contents())($scope);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick with `ng-if` approach for the moment, but your solution is quite interesting as well.

Comment: Sure, I'm glad you found it interesting.